# How to avoid forcing deep evaluation for the sole purpose of catching imprecise exceptions?

Tags: haskell

The issue I'm having is about error management in Haskell. I've been reading from many resources about this, and I have understood that there are a few possibilities, most notably:

- for pure, non-monadic functions:

  - use `Either` / `MayBe`
  - throw "impure" / "imprecise" exceptions, that can only be caught in `IO`
- for pure, monadic functions:

  - any of the above
  - use `Control.Monad.Except` (or similar approaches).
- for `IO` functions:

  - throw and catch in `IO`

The issue I'm having is about finding the right approach with an existing application.

#### The `force` approach

This is the approach currently used in my real application.
The following toy example tries to be a minimal reproducible example of that.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass, DeriveGeneric #-}

module Main where

import System.IO
import GHC.Generics ( Generic )
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Exception
import Control.DeepSeq

data Expr = V Int
          | Div Expr Expr
          deriving (Eq,Show,NFData,Generic)

-- A minimalistic state for the State monad 
data Env = Env {
    l :: [Int]
  }
type EnvM a = State Env a

-- resolves an Expr to an Int value
calcExpr :: Expr -> Int
calcExpr (V v) = v
calcExpr (Div e1 e2) =
  let v2 = calcExpr e2
  in  if v2 == 0
      then throw DivideByZero
      else calcExpr e1 `div` v2

-- calls calcExpr
-- also keeps a list of resolved values in the state
evalExpr :: Expr -> EnvM Int
evalExpr e = do
  let v = calcExpr e
  env <- get
  put $ env{l = v:(l env)}
  return v

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- the first 10 expressions that evaluate to an even number, from a decreasing, infinite integer list
  -- when executed, "i" will reach 0, and a division by 0 will occur
  let exprs = [ Div (V 100) (V i) | i <- [5,4..] ]
      values = evalState (mapM evalExpr exprs) Env{l = []}
      results = zip exprs (take 10 $ filter even values)

  -- evaluate, catching possible exceptions
  -- catching will not work without using "force"
  evaluation <- try $ evaluate $ force results

  -- handle possible errors
  putStrLn $
    case evaluation of
      Left e -> "Exception was caught in Main: " ++ show (e :: ArithException)
      Right rs -> show rs
```

The output shows that the exception thrown by a pure function was caught correctly in `IO`:

```
Exception was caught in Main: divide by zero
```

Removing `force` (thus `try $ evaluate results` or `try $ pure results`) dos not catch the exception at the right place:

```
errorHandlingTest: divide by zero
```

The advantage of the `force` approach is that exceptions can be thrown from anywhere and they are caught correctly.

However, I found that forcing deep evaluation makes my real application much slower. Hence, this question.

#### The `ExceptT` approach

Since my real application relies heavily on the `State`-based environment, it seems right to extend it with `ExceptT`:

```hs
module Main where

import System.IO
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Except

data Expr = V Int
          | Mul Expr Expr
          | Div Expr Expr
          deriving (Eq,Show)

data Env = Env {
    l :: [Int]
  }

type EnvM a = ExceptT String (State Env) a

calcExpr :: Expr -> EnvM Int
calcExpr (V v) = return v
calcExpr (Div e1 e2) = do
  v1 <- calcExpr e1
  v2 <- calcExpr e2
  if v2 == 0
  then throwError "Division By Zero detected"
  else return $ v1 `div` v2

evalExpr :: Expr -> EnvM Int
evalExpr e = do
  -- Keep a list of values in the state.
  -- Not particularly useful, just for the example
  v <- calcExpr e
  env <- get
  put $ env{l = v:(l env)}
  return v

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- the first 10 expressions that evaluate to an even number, from a decreasing, infinite integer list
  -- when executed, "i" will reach 0, and a division by 0 will occur
  let exprs = [ Div (V 100) (V i) | i <- [5,4..] ]
      values = evalState (runExceptT (mapM evalExpr exprs)) Env{l = []}

  -- handle possible errors
  putStrLn $
    case values of
      Left e -> "Exception was caught in Main: " ++ show e
      Right rs -> show $ zip exprs (take 10 $ filter even rs)
```

This doesn't force any deep evaluation and gives the expected result:

```
Exception was caught in Main: "Division By Zero detected"
```

However, function `calcExpr` is no longer a pure non-monadic function. I consider this a show-stopper. In my real code, have many pure functions that do not need the `State` monad at all. Being forced to rewrite them as I did with `calcExpr` seems to me an indication that something isn't right.

#### The `Either` / `Maybe` approach

`Either` and `Maybe` look like the correct way to handle errors in pure functions (I won't show the whole example):

```hs
calcExpr :: Expr -> Maybe Int
calcExpr (V v) = Just v
calcExpr (Div e1 e2) =
  let v1 = calcExpr e1
      v2 = calcExpr e2
  in  case (v1,v2) of
        (_      , Just 0) -> Nothing
        (Just x, Just y) -> Just (x `div` y)
        _ -> Nothing
```

However, this also introduces quite some type overhead, which I fear would become not easily manageable for real applications.

#### What else?

None of these approaches seems to fit what I suspect are very common needs.

- Are there approaches I didn't consider?
- Is there something I missed within these approaches?

Comment: You want to change how you do error handling, but you don't want to modify the functions that throw errors? Sure seems like you've painted yourself into a corner with those requirements.

Comment: @DanielWagner it's not that I don't want to out of personal preferences. Those changes do not seem right to me. I'm hoping that I'm wrong in that, and that either I'm not implementing them well enough or I'm not seeing some other possibilities. Am I wrong thinking that reimplementing a function for `State` when it doesn't need it is weird? Or that using `Maybe` everywhere makes it too complicated? Can either approach be implemented in a smarter way? (Usually that's the case for mere mortals like myself and Haskell)

Comment: @corruz "forcing deep evaluation makes my real application much slower" Does the real code by chance call `force` multiple times over the same results? Do the result get consumed in any other way, like by being written to disk or to a network socket?

Comment: No, only at top level like in the example.

Comment: @cornuz In the example code that uses `force`, it seems that you are forcing both the results of `evalExpr`  *and the original expressions*. But, assuming the original expression trees don't hide exceptions, that's inefficient: `force` traverses them for no additional safety. Perhaps you could do the `zip exprs` after forcing the results.

Comment: @danidiaz you're right, but that doesn't happen in the real code.

Comment: Recent versions of GHC have gained the ability to define `UnliftedDatatypes` https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/primitives.html#extension-UnliftedDatatypes which might avoid the need for "deepseq-ing". But they are very new, lack may conveniences, aren't compatible with common typeclasess like `Show`, `Functor`... and their actual usefulness might heavily depend on the details of the situation.

Comment: @cornuz You don't need to include `State` if you don't want to. `calcExpr :: MonadError String m => m Int` works fine as an annotation and specializes to `EnvM` without trouble. I don't think using `Maybe` everywhere is too complicated, but it's not really different from the `ExceptT` way, either, once you start using the monad syntax to avoid all that pattern matching. (e.g. your `calcExpr :: Expr -> Maybe Int` could also be written ```do { x <- calcExpr e1; y <- calcExpr e2; if y == 0 then Nothing else return (x `div` y) }```... almost identical to your `ExceptT` version.)

Comment: Have you considered pushing your `force` farther up the call stack? What I mean is: if `force` is slowing your application down, then almost certainly it is evaluating more of its argument than your program otherwise would. So, instead of writing `x <- evaluate (force foo); print (computeActualResult x)`, can you write `x <- evaluate (force (computeActualResult foo)); print x`? Obviously your actual `IO` action will be more complicated than `print`, but the basic thing I'm advocating here is delaying `force` far enough that it doesn't cause your program to be less lazy, just more eager.

Comment: @DanielWagner you are very right about `calcExpr :: MonadError String m => m Int` annotation. Somehow I didn't think about that. This actually makes my argument against this approach much weaker. I still wish I didn't have to use a Monad and the do notation at all, but now it becomes more a matter of style than substance. It seems that real applications end up leaving very few opportunities for writing non-monadic functions.